# Is it possible to use a string to call a class function/attribute in c++?

Tags: c++, mapping

I am trying to call a class member function/attribute based on an input string.
Here is what I'm struggling with:

```
template <typename T>
class Signalling
{
public:
    T                   value;
};

class Signals
{
public:
    Signalling<bool>    s1; 
    Signalling<int>     s2; 
};

void main(){
   std::string name = "s1";
   Signalling<int> value = 5; // this will have different types

   Signals newSignal;

   if (name == "s1")
       newSignal.s1 = value;

   else if (name == "s2")
       newSignal.s2 = value;

// what I actually want to reach in some form is:
// newSignal.(name) = value !!??

}
```

So basically I need to call the according class member which has the same name as the input string.
The above code does work with if/else, but since the number of signals (here s1, s2..) are too many it wouldn't be possible to go through all if cases and I need to find a work around.

I already tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557881/convert-string-character-to-class-member-method-in-c), but I couldn't get it up running,  :\

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: On second thought, the different types make this very different from what you found in that link.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "number of signals [...] are too many"? Do you plan to have hundreds of them? 
2. Can you show an example of how `value` will "have different types"? I struggle to see what you plan to extend it into (where will you get value/name pairs from, and how you'll make it pass the type-checker).

Comment: Thought about this for a while now and can't think of a way to make this work dynamically without it being more trouble than it's worth (and probably violating a few language rules).

Comment: @user4581301 it depends on what you are trying to achieve. There may be a solution, but at the moment the question looks like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you can make all of the fields be the same type, such as using `std::variant`, then you can use a `std::map` holding either pointer-to-member or lambdas to solve this.

Comment: @Scheff being a textual format is not required.

Comment: Thanks everyone, by Signals I mean s1, s2... which is a long list that will be read from csv file at the begining and contains the initial values of the signal and more. There is sctually a loop which goes through this list.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't way to do this, instead of if, you can use switch,  also, in your link is good idea to use std::map.
If you use switch, don't forget to use break; The shorter way than switch is using condition?true : false, but it may create unclear code.